# How did Ripley know where to find these characters?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

In *Alien* 2003 director's cut edition, after

> activating the self-destruct system, Ripley goes down a ladder to a part of a ship, where she finds Lambert and Brett, and kills them.

How did Ripley know where they are/head to this place, in case she didn't know she would find them there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [the shooting script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/alien_shooting.html) we learn that she heard crying.

> Ripley running toward engine room.
>   Out of breath.
>   Exhausted she stops, gulps for air.
>   **Suddenly, ahead of her, the sound of human weeping.**
>   She moves quietly ahead until the source of the sound is directly under her feet.
>   She is standing on a round metal plate.
>   Ripley starts to remove the disc.

The [official novelisation](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Alien_(novel)) contains much the same description.

> All that thinking brought her back to her senses. Gulping for breath,
>   she slowed and took stock of her surroundings. She'd run the length of
>   the ship. Now she found herself standing alone in the middle of the
>   engine room.
>
> She heard something and stopped breathing. It was repeated, and she
>   let out a cautious sigh. The sound was familiar, human. It was the
>   sound of weeping.
>
> Still cradling the flamethrower, she walked slowly around the room
>   until the source of the noise lay directly below her. She found she
>   was standing on a companionway cover, a round metal disc. Keeping half
>   her attention on the well-lit chamber surrounding her, she knelt and
>   removed the disc. A ladder descended into the near darkness.